# Why can't I compare a constant instance of a class with a non-constant instance of the same class?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, constants, operator-overloading

I have the following function:

```
#include <cstdint>
using int_32 = int32_t;

bool func(const Coord<int_32> c)
{
    for (Coord<int_32> i : boxes)
        if (c == i)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

`Coord<int_32>` is a struct with two members of type **int** (**int32_t**).

Here is its overloaded **==** operator:

```
bool operator == (const Coord<T> &p)
{
    if (this -> x == p.x &&
        this -> y == p.y)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me an error at `if (c == i)`:

> error: passing 'const Coord<int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: Make the `operator==` const. That allows the lhs to be const. At the moment `if (i == c)` should compile since the rhs argument is const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your comparison:

```
if (c == i)
```

the variable `c` is `const`. However, your `operator==` is not *const-qualified*, so the left hand side of `==` is required to be non-const.

The correct fix for this is to mark `operator==` as `const` if it's a member function:

```
bool operator == (const Coord<T> &p) const {
                                 //  ^^^^^
```

Comment: And will this affect anything else? Will it work then even if the lhs operand is not const?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can try it out yourself to be sure :) `const` qualification means the lhs is *allowed* to be `const`, but it's not required to be.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) But then can I put `const` to **all** the functions, even if they don't necessarily need it, and nothing will change? Or should I not do that?

Comment: Yes, you should do that. Then you'll see that some functions *can't* be const, because the point of those functions is to modify the object. In those cases, remove the const :)